# problem with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to upload an image and show a live preview. I have a form with id `prescriptionform`, file input with id `scaninput1` and `<div>` for preview with id `preview`.

jQuery code:

```
$('#scaninput1').live('change', function() { 
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="scripts/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#prescriptionform").ajaxForm({
        //alert("Hiiiiiii");
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();
});
```

Code is running and I am uploading the image, but it's not submitting to `ajaximage.php`.

My HTML code:

```html
<form name='prescriptionform' id="prescriptionform"  method='post'  enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <div id="preview"></div>
    <input type="file" id="scaninput1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload a file directly with an ajax form submit.

You will have to use some other technology to make this work.

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)